# How to turn on azure machines using github actions?

Tags: azure, github-actions

I have three windows self-hosted runners for github actions.

Need to turn on the machines when the pipeline runs.

And want to turn off the machine once the pipeline finishes.

But, want to make sure, other pipelines are not running before turning off the machine.

Also, with azure, unlike aws, shuttting down the machine doesn't stop the billing. So, we need to turnoff from azure portal/api. Thought to run that command at the end of pipeline but again, it needs another github runner(either self-hosted or provided by github actions) to do that step, if I do in the same runner, it won't provide the return code correctly as the runner will be turned off.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how that did not work (error messages etc).

Comment: @rethab I added description, not commands to show error message. Kindly go through it once again.